# Calculate multiple variables integral with change of variables

Tags: real-analysis, multiple-integral

> Let $E = (0,1) \times (0,1) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Let the function $\Phi : E \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by
>   $$ \Phi(x,y) = (e^{x+y}, e^{x-y}), \qquad \text{with } (x,y) \in E. $$
>   Determine the area of $\Phi(E)$.

**What I have tried so far:**

 Let $\Phi(u,v) = (x,y) = (e^{u+v}, e^{u-v})$, and let $f(x,y) = f(e^{u+v}, e^{u-v})$.

We know the change of variables formula
$$ \iint_{\Phi(E)} f(x,y) dA = \iint_E f(e^{u+v}, e^{u-v}) |\det(D\Phi)| \, dA. $$
With $D\Phi$ the Jacobian of $\Phi$, so $D\Phi = \begin{pmatrix} e^{u+v} & e^{u+v} \\ e^{u-v} & -e^{u-v} \end{pmatrix}$. Then calculating the determinant gives $\det(D\Phi) = -2 e^{2u}$. Substituting that in the formula gives

$$ \iint_{\Phi(E)} f(x,y) dA = \iint_E f(e^{u+v}, e^{u-v}) 2e^{2u} \, dA. $$

But I don't know how to go further with this. Do I have to define $f$ more specific than I did? And if so, how?

Or is this not the way to go about solving this problem?

Comment: Area of $\Phi(E)$ is $\displaystyle \iint_{\Phi(E)} 1 \; dA  = \displaystyle \iint_E 1 | \text{det}(D \Phi)| \; dA$

Comment: @user288742 Aaah, yeah I recognize that. I think I forgot about that, thanks! So that gives us $\iint_{\Phi(E)} 1 dA = \iint_E 2e^{2x} dA = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 2e^{2x} dydx = \int_0^1[2y e^{2x}]_0^1 dx = \int_0^1 2 e^{2x} dx = [e^{2x}]_0^1 = e^2 - 1 $. Right?

Comment: Looks good to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the comments helped me getting to an answer, and thus no answer is needed anymore, this is what was in the comments.

We noted that the area of $\Phi(E)$ is

$$ \iint_{\Phi(E)} 1\ dA = \iint_E 1 |\det(D\Phi)|\ dA\,. $$

Then, using that we know $\det(D\Phi) = -2e^{2x}$, we can use this and the boundaries given for $E$ to calculate the area. Thus follows

$$\begin{align}
 \iint_{\Phi(E)} 1\ dA 
&= \iint_E 2e^{2x}\ dA \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 2e^{2x}\ dydx \\
&= \int_0^1 \left[2ye^{2x}\right]_0^1\ dx \\
&= \int_0^1 2e^{2x}\ dx \\
&= \left[e^{2x} \right]_0^1 \\
&= e^2 -1 \,. 
\end{align}$$